# Create String Array with XML attributes in Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to pull information from a onenote notebook. The only way I've found to be able to is to get the hierarchy of the notebook, then pull all the attributes so I can use them to pull the actual content of a page. Following is an example of the XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one:Notebooks xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote">
    <one:Notebook name="Notebook" nickname="Notebook" ID="**********" path="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" color="**********">
        <one:Section name="**********" ID="**********" path="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" color="**********">
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="1"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="1"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="1"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
            <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
        </one:Section>
    </one:Notebook>
</one:Notebooks>
```

I was able to pull the attributes by using the following:

```
Dim oneNote = New OneNote.Application()
oneNote.GetHierarchy(Nothing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsPages, strXML)
        Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument()
        xdoc.LoadXml(strXML)
    For Each Element As XmlElement In xdoc.SelectNodes("//*")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Processing element with name: " & Element.Name & Environment.NewLine
        For Each Attribute As XmlAttribute In Element.Attributes
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Convert.ToChar(Keys.Tab) & Attribute.Name & ": " & Attribute.Value & Environment.NewLine
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine
    Next
```

However when I try to pull specific attributes by name it comes back with a namespace error.

```
For Each node As XmlNode In xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//one:Notebooks/one:Notebook/one:Section")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & node.Attributes.ItemOf("name").InnerText & Environment.NewLine
Next
```

I would like to be able to create a string array with the name of the section, the name of the page, the ID of the page, and the page level. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With an XmlDocument you have to use an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to use namespaces:

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim notebook As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0"?>
                                    <one:Notebooks xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote">
                                        <one:Notebook name="Notebook" nickname="Notebook" ID="**********" path="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" color="**********">
                                            <one:Section name="SectionName1" ID="**********" path="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" color="**********">
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="1"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="1"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="1"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
                                                <one:Page ID="**********" name="**********" dateTime="**********" lastModifiedTime="**********" pageLevel="2"/>
                                            </one:Section>
                                        </one:Notebook>
                                    </one:Notebooks>

        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(notebook.ToString())

        Dim nsm As New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
        nsm.AddNamespace("one", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote")

        For Each node As XmlNode In xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//one:Notebooks/one:Notebook/one:Section", nsm)
            Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes.ItemOf("name").InnerText)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> SectionName1

And I'm sure you can continue from there with that knowledge

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the newer `System.Xml.Linq` types (.NET 3.5+), then you could use the built-in support for XML Literals and LINQ to XML, which allows you to import the namespace:

```vb
Imports <xmlns:one = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote">
'...
Dim oneNote = New OneNote.Application()
Dim strXML As String = Nothing
oneNote.GetHierarchy(Nothing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsPages, strXML)
Dim xml = XDocument.Parse(strXML)
Dim pages = (
    From s In xml...<one:Section>
    From p In s.<one:Page>
    Select $"Section={s.@name} Page={p.@name} PageID={p.@ID} PageLevel={p.@pageLevel}"
).ToList()
```

You could modify the `Select` clause to return something else - e.g. an anonymous type with the properties you need - instead of a string as shown above (which uses VB 14 string interpolation, so requires VS2015+ or modify to the old syntax).